# auto launch application beacon every time when detect beacon signal

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, android-bluetooth

I follow this reference [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) and i wonder

1. That it's possible to launch my application every times when I'm enter the beacon region or I'm already in beacon region and my device detect the beacon signal. Because now boostrapnotifier class still recall when power connection change

2.Can I define the radius of beacon region such as 5 meters. Because now radius is too wide for my use case.

Comment: You can answer all this by just implementing and checking if it works for you or not :)

Comment: From doc said that is OS limitation. I has stuck with this issue for 2 day and find the way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is possible, yes.

The `RegionBootstrap` class is designed to auto launch your app into the background to scan for beacons, and send callbacks whenever you enter/exit a beacon region.  Because the operating system may kill your app to save memory, the library is designed to re-launch the app so its background scanning service can continue operating under a few conditions:

1. Within 5 minutes of being killed using an Android `AlarmManager`.
2. If the above fails, on a power connect/disconnect operation.
3. On phone boot.

Following the reference you mention, this behavior should be automatic.

While **you can't define a radius of a `Region`, you can add filtering logic that does something similar.**  Once you get a callback to `didEnterRegion`, start ranging for beacons in that region.  In the ranging callback, if you see that `beacon.getDistance() < 5.0` you can execute your logic that you want to happen only if the beacon is less than five meters away.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I  more understand about how library working and OS limitation. I'll try to apply my application.

Comment: If I create broadcastreceiver class to looking for bluetooth state when bluetooth is turn-on how can I start scan in onReceive method

Comment: If you set up the RegionBootstrap in an Application class as per the examples, this will be automatic.  The library will start trying to scan when the app starts up, and if bluetooth is off it simply won't be able to do so.  Once it is on it will start scanning automatically.